# React Native checkbox handle

Tags: reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I have country codes from a file, I render it like that,
it returns all country names and codes perfectly.

```
               <TouchableOpacity 
           style={st.oneCode}
           onPress={selectItem}>
              <View
                 style={[
                    st.filterCheckMarkWrapper,
                    check === false &&
                       st.filterCheckmarkInactiveColor,
                 ]}>
                 {check === true && (
                    <View style={st.filterCheckmark} />
                 )}
              </View><Text style={st.CodeText}>
                 {item.countryName}: +{item.phoneCode}
              </Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
```

but when check is true, all of the text are checked, how can i fix it?

Comment: Check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `check` variable/state, you can either add a `checklist` or `checked` property in the Country object.

**Note:** I'll only explain the second one.

So, you have to add `checked` property to your Country object.

Then your source will be:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
    style={st.oneCode}
    onPress={selectItem}>
    <View
        style={[
        st.filterCheckMarkWrapper,
        item.checked === false &&
            st.filterCheckmarkInactiveColor,
        ]}>
        {item.checked === true && (
        <View style={st.filterCheckmark} />
        )}
    </View><Text style={st.CodeText}>
        {item.countryName}: +{item.phoneCode}
    </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And inside your `onPress` event you have to toggle the `checked` property.

**E.g:**

```
function selectItem(item: Country) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    //your other works
}
```